# How can i get an event after end of the Animation?

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Any one please tell me how can i get an event after completion of the animation on the Sprite ? 
I am using cocos2d frame work,

Some part of my code is like this..

```
-(void)playerTouchHurdlesOnFlore:(LHContactInfo*)contact
{

    if(!isHurdlesAnimStart)
    {
        isHurdlesAnimStart=YES;

        onGround=NO;

        [player stopAnimation];

        //[player setIsRelativeAnchorPoint:NO];

        // I want to call any event or function after end of the this "Fall_Down" animation.
        [player startAnimationNamed:@"Fall_Down"];

        jumpCounter = 0.3f;
        player.body->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(0,2.0f), player.body->GetPosition());
    }

}
```

Please tell me any solution or give me some idea if you have,

Thanks in advance ,

:)

Comment: so can you tell me, what solution are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the docs of sprite and cocoa2d, there should be a delegate method like

```
 - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)finished
```

but this method is for Core Animation

Comment: there is no such delegate methods in cocos2d

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create callback using `CCCallFunc`

```
id animation = // any of your action, CCAnimate, CCMoveTo, etc.
id callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onAnimationEnd)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: animation two: callback];
[nodeToAnimate runAction: sequence];
```

of course, you can use any target and selector you want as callback